# zenity --calendar how to convert result to 'find -mtime'

Tags: bash, calendar, find, zenity

I have to use `zenity --calendar` to read date from user. After it, I have to use it in program `find` as a parameter of option `-mtime`. Zenity return date in format like `20.09.2014` and I have no idea how to count how many days ago it was, what is necessary in `-mtime` option.
Could anyone help me and tell me how to do it? I've just started learning about bash and this is part of one exercise.
Thanks for your help! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `date` command to convert dates to seconds since epoch, calculate the difference in seconds and convert this to days. This looks as follows:

```
pickedDate=$(zenity --calendar)
pickedSeconds=$(date --utc +%s --date "$pickedDate")
nowSeconds=$(date --utc +%s)
diffDays=$(( ($nowSeconds - $pickedSeconds)/86400 ))
```

or in one line:

```
echo  $(( ($(date --utc +%s) - $(date --utc +%s --date $(zenity --calendar)))/86400 ))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have

- `zenity` which has a `--date-format` option which can be useful to return the date as you expect it, i.e.

  ```
  $ zenity --calendar --date-format='%Y-%m-%d'
  2015-08-03
  ```
- `date` which can parse the passed date with the `-d` option and return it expressed as a unix timestamp
- `find` which expects `-mtime` expressed as days

I think I'd do something like this

```
#!/bin/bash
theDate=$(date +'%s' -d $(zenity --calendar --date-format='%Y-%m-%d'))
now=$(date +'%s')
diffDays=$(( ($now - $theDate) / 86400 ))

find /tmp -daystart -mtime -$diffDays
```

Comment: `zenity --calendar --date-format='%D'` --> _mm/dd/yy_